# What are these "unknown key 'BUS'" errors during boot?

Tags: boot, udev

I'm trying to optimize the boot process on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop, and while analyzing the `/var/log/boot.log` file I found many `unknown key 'BUS'...`. How can I get rid of them?

Here's the relevant part of `boot.log`:

```
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:21
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:21'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:23
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:23'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:29
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:29'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:30
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:30'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:31
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:31'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:33
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:33'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:34
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:34'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'BUS' in /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:35
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules:35'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'SYSFS{idVendor}' in /etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:3
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:3'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'SYSFS{idProduct}' in /etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:4
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:4'
udevd[358]: unknown key 'SYSFS{idProduct}' in /etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:7
udevd[358]: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules:7'
```

P.S.: On this machine I firstly installed Ubuntu 9.04, then it was upgraded all Ubuntu versions up to 12.04. Now I'm using `xubuntu-desktop` as desktop.

Comment: If you click on the upper right corner (button with wheel symbol), and then choose 'Applications to start'.. What do you see?

Comment: Sorry Lucio, I'm using XUbuntu (the XFCE version), so I don't know what you mean with the "Applications to start" option. Do you know which program is launched when you click on that button?.

Answer (score 1):

The log messages tell you they are from [`udev`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), and the errors are in the two files `/lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules`.  The question is from where did those two configuration files originate?

Files in `/etc/` are configuration files.  As the system administrator you may edit them.  Did you create `15-huawei.rules`?  If so, then it is your responsibility to update it.  If it was installed by a package, then first see if an update is available and if not then file a bug.

Files in `/lib/` are installed by packages, and are not intended to be modified by the system administrator.

Run the command

```
dpkg -S /lib/udev/rules.d/10-blackberry.rules
```

and

```
dpkg -S /etc/udev/rules.d/15-huawei.rules
```

to determine what package, if any, provided those two files.

The udev package's [Changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/udev/udev_175-0ubuntu1/changelog) shows "*The long deprecated keys: SYSFS=, ID=, BUS= have been removed*".  You have two files that use those keys,  which are no longer valid.  Either you don't really need those configuration files (do you have Blackberry and Huawei devices and plug them into your computer?) or they simply need to be updated to match the current version of udev.

Comment: Thanks dsh, the dpkg -S ... results are: barry-util (now removed because I no longer connect a Blackberry) and, for the Huawei the result is "dpkg-query: path not found..." (the message is in spanish). So, can I just delete the 15-huawei rule?.

Comment: If you don't connect any Huawei devices to your computer, then you can remove it.  Alternatively I think you can just change the `SYSFS{idVendor}` and `SYSFS{idProduct}` keys to `ATTR{idVendor}` and `ATTR{idProduct}` to update the rules for the current version of udev.